# Вывод значения кнопки в текстовое поле

Tags: javascript

Есть две кнопки со своим значением и текстовое поле. Как в поле отобразить value из кнопки на экране? Код ниже почему-то не работает:

```
 <button type="button" class="button_style" value="1" name="one">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="button_style" value="2" name="two">2</button>

    <input type="text" id="result" name="result" class="result" /><br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var but_val = '';
            $(".button_style").click(function(){
                but_val += $(this).val();
                $("#result").val(but_val);
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: @LLIAKAJI ваш код [работает][1]. Проверьте, подключен ли jQuery и вообще посмотрите ошибки в консоли


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/m5u4vg7w/

Comment: Ваш скрипт сам по себе рабочий.  
1. Проверьте, подключен ли jQuery.  
2. Попробуйте убрать обертку $(document).ready();  
3. Проверьте консоль на наличие ошибок.

Comment: у меня не работает, о каком  jQuery идется речь?

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, вы используете синтаксис библиотеки jQuery (http://jquery.com), но при этом не знаете, что это? Удивительное сплошь и рядом.
1) Выучите синтаксис javascript.  
2) Подключите jQuery (http://jquery.com/download/), раз используете его синтаксис.

Comment: >о каком jQuery идется речь?

так вы этот код откуда-то взяли? Тогда вам имеет смысл сначала ознакомиться с основами js и почитать, что такое jQuery (раз уж вы в своем примере его используете)

Comment: Все скачал, и заработало.

Comment: >все скачал и заработало

@LLIAKAJI вы все же ознакомьтесь с тем, как это работает, иначе впоследствии возникнут проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, JQ для этого не нужен - достаточно обычного js:

```
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="javascript:daivalue('1');" class="button_style" value="1" name="one">1</button>
<button type="button" id="2" onclick="javascript:daivalue('2');"  class="button_style" value="2" name="two">2</button>

<input type="text" id="result" name="result" class="result" /><br />

<script>
function daivalue (id) {
var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
document.getElementById('result').value = value;
}

</script>
```